# How to clear PCR7 binding not possible?

Tags: windows, encryption

I have been unable to find the requirements for PCR7 binding in Windows 11 Home edition.  I have looked at various search results such as [PCR7 Configuration Binding Not Possible](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/pcr7-configuration-binding-not-possible/ba7aeb33-b1cb-459e-a3e8-c0ad0a17975f), [How do I enable PCR7 bindings?](https://finddiffer.com/how-do-i-enable-pcr7-bindings/) and [Windows Server shows PCR7 configuration as "Binding not possible"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/deployment/pcr7-configuration-binding-not-possible).  I believe my problem is that the answers I'm finding deal with clearing binding not supported, instead of not possible.  Seems like MS could be more clear on this.

These results of the search point to needing 3 things.

1. TPM enabled
2. UEFI Bios enabled
3. Secure boot enabled

When I open msinfo and inspect the system summary I see that BIOS mode is UEFI, Secure Boot State is On.

I have both a dedicated TPM module and the fTPM from the Ryzen CPU.  Currently the dedicated TPM is active, but I have tried both.  When I run tpm.msc I see status "The TPM is ready to use" for either TPM source.

I then opened an elevated PS and ran `Confirm-SecureBootUEFI` and get `True`.

All my drives are setup up as GPT.  What are the requirements for PCR7 binding or how do I figure out what is making binding not possible?

This machine is a Ryzen 5600X in an msi MAG B550 Tomahawk.  MB bios is dated 03/2023 and the chipset is dated 05/2023.

Comment: You confirmed all requirements except for BitLocker Protection being enabled which is one of the reasons for all the other requirements or perhaps I don’t understand the problem. Especially since two of the three links are talking about the message you have received instead of “not supported”.

Comment: @Ramhound I believe there are 2 types of encryptions available.  See [Turn on device encryption](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/turn-on-device-encryption-0c453637-bc88-5f74-5105-741561aae838).  Home does not come with BitLocker.

Comment: Same problem here I have all 4 requirements, you missed one by the way: ***modern standby***. I have Windows 11 Pro, and I believe you should look if that's not an exclusive feature.